# Inverse of a Matrix(shortcut and tricks)

Tags: matrices

Can someone tell me if there is any shortcut or trick of finding the inverse of a matrix and not by elementary operations? Also is it possible to judge an inverse of a matrix by judging the options given to me?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the options of inverse with given matrix to get identity matrix.(check one / two values).

Comment: The way to thank someone here is to upvote (if you have enough points) and/or "accept" the answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

For a $2\times2$ matrix, there's a simple formula. $$\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}^{-1}={1\over ad-bc}\pmatrix{d&-b\cr -c&a\cr}$$ provided $ad-bc\ne0$.

For a $3\times3$ matrix $A$, you can construct the matrix $A'$by letting its $ij$-entry be the determinant of the matrix you get from $A$ by deleting row $j$ and column $i$, and then multiplying that determinant by $-1$ if $i+j$ is odd. Then $AA'=(\det A)I$, so you get $A^{-1}=(\det A)^{-1}A'$, provided $\det A\ne0$. Moreover, you don't have to calculate all of $AA'$ (except to check your arithmetic), as it suffices to compute the $(1,1)$-entry.

Comment: This is really wonderful